# Создать массив из 10 случайных чисел

Tags: массивы, c

Создать массив из 10 случайных чисел в диапазоне от -20 до 20. Определить среднее арифметическое положительных элементов массива.

**Обновление 1**

Сделала вот что:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void main()

{
setlocale(0, "rus");
    const int n = 10;
    int num[n];
int num_1 = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    num_1 = rand() % 41 - 20;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << num_1<< endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Обновление 2**

```
setlocale(0, "rus");

const int n = 10;

int num[n];

int num_1 = 0;

srand(time(0));

num_1 = rand() % 41 - 20;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

{

cout << num_1 << endl;

}
```

Не получается вывести все 10 чисел разными.

Comment: @ma1ina, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: 1. Перенесите код в вопрос и отформатируйте его 

2. А не получается что?

Comment: Вопрос обновлен.

Comment: @ma1ina еще раз - перенесите код в вопрос и отформатируйте - его очень неудобно читать

Answer (score 2):

[[@ma1ina](/users/30438/ma1ina)](/users/30438/ma1ina), а они и не должны таким образом получаться разными (даже если исправить лежащую на поверхности ошибку в Вашей программе).

Ведь это же **случайные** числа. Очередное число м.б. **любым**. Вероятность, что оно будет равно предыдущему (ну, конечно, если это *действительно случайные* числа) 1/41.

--

Если Вам нужно, чтобы все 10 были разными, то потребуется проверять, а не было ли ранее уже такого же. Самое простое (но не самое эффективное) решение -- это сравнение во вложенном цикле нового числа с уже запомненными.